# What is the internal representation of a NULL value in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, null

In SQLite, a zero byte string ('') is stored as text type, and is different from a NULL value, which is stored as a NULL type.  How is a NULL value stored internally in SQLite, and how is it different from an empty string?
 Given that each value in a table is stored with an identifier indicating it to be one of 5 types (Integer, Float, Text, Blob, or Null), and that one would want not to have to reorganize a table every time a new value is entered taking up more space than an original value, I am guessing that in addition to the byte identifying the data type of the value, there is another entry -- a pointer to the actual value stored in a stack somewhere, and possibly a third entry giving the length in bytes of the entry.  It may be, then, that a null value is indicated by a type value of NULL followed by a null pointer.  This would permit a 0 length string ('') to be different from a null value.
Am I anywhere close to how SQLite handles this?
Larry Hunsicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQLite's on-disk [record format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format), one byte is needed for each column to specify its type and length. There are no separate pointers or lengths, and a NULL value and a zero-length string both have a content size of zero bytes, so the serial type byte is all the storage that is needed.

(When some data is updated, the entire row is rewritten.)